# Is a one line named wildcard re-export possible?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Take following folder structure as an example:

```
example.ts
outer/
|--- inner/
   |--- index.ts
   |--- file1.ts
   |--- file2.ts
|--- index.ts
```

**Content of** `file1.ts`

```
export class FileOneClass{/**/}
export interface IFileOneInterface{/**/}
```

**Content of** `file2.ts`:

```
export class FileTwoClass{/**/}
export interface IFileTwoInterface{/**/}
```

**Content of** `outer/inner/index.ts`:

```
export { FileOneClass, IFileOneInterface } from "./file1.ts"
export { FileTwoClass, IFileTwoInterface } from "./file2.ts"
```

**Content of** `outer/index.ts`:

```
import * as InnerImport from "./inner";
export const Inner = InnerImport;
```

**Content of** `example.ts`:

```
import { Inner } from "./outer"

    function exampleUsage(){
      console.log(Inner.FileOneClass)
      console.log(Inner.FileOneInterface)

      console.log(Inner.FileTwoClass)
      console.log(Inner.FileTwoInterface)
    }
```

**My Question:**

Is there a way to write the export statement in `outer/index.ts` into one single line?

```
// Ugly:
import * as InnerImport from "./inner";
export const Inner = InnerImport;

// Desired is something like this:
export * as Inner from "./inner"; // This line leads to a error!
```

Comment: Drop the `const`, simplify to `import * as Innner from "./inner"; export {Inner};`

Comment: That's an improvement but still just a pseudo one liner.

Comment: That's how I meant it - as an improvement, not as a one-liner. The single line is a just a limitation of code in comments :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, sure (just kidding):

```
import * as InnerImport from "./inner"; export const Inner = InnerImport;
```

But there is unfortunately no way to rename and wrap the exports in one statement.

Comment: Starting with typescript 3.8 syntax like [`export * as ns`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-8-beta/#export-star-as-namespace-syntax) is possible!